# Unable to create a Message selector in JMS properly

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp

I can retrieve some data from a server which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <responseMetadata>
        <httpCode>200</httpCode>
        <errorType>Ok</errorType>
        <description>Success</description>
        <cappingLimit>333</cappingLimit>
        <queryString>........</queryString>
    </responseMetadata>
    <responseHeader>
        <recordType>some record type long</recordType>
        <fileType>my_file_type</fileType>
    </responseHeader>
    <responseBody>
        <responseList>
            <item>
                <recordType>some record type short</recordType>
                <header2>fdsfdsfds</header2>
                <header3>fdsfdsssfds</header3>
                <header4>fdsfd2222sfds</header4>
            </item>
```

It also have a push STOMP service. I want to be able to receive the same data via it. 
But not all the data  which is sent by default but only the data which has

"recordType" = some record type long in the header or, which is the same, "some record type short" in the body. I think it's not allowed to filter by body, though.

How can I properly filter it? I know I have to use

```
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic, "recordType='some record type long'");


// or
messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(topic, "recordType='some record type short'"); // not allowed?
```

Anyway, this hasn't worked. Maybe the selector is wrong? Here it describes how to create one https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031980_.htm#q031980_
but how should I create it in my particular case? And what's JMSType?

P.S. My app is a consumer, not a producer of the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the document linked to your questions, JMS selectors work with JMS standard or user **properties**... not on the content of the message payload...

If you want to "select" message based on "recordType", you have to add "recordType" as a property to your messages

Comment: **If you want to "select" message based on "recordType", you have to add "recordType" as a property to your messages** how? given that "My app is a consumer, not a producer of the messages."?

Comment: When creating the message in java:

    TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
    msg.setText(<payload>);
    msg.setJMSXXX(...) to set the XXX JMS standard property: check the doc

    msg.setStringProperty("recordType",<value>);
    msg.setXXXProperty(<name>,<value>) ->to set int, long etc properties

[JMS Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html)
[JMS Message API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html)

Comment: GIVEN THAT "MY APP IS A CONSUMER, NOT A PRODUCER OF THE MESSAGES"

Comment: If you can not change the way JMS messages are produced to add user properties, then you will not be able to use JMS selectors as JMS selectors only work with JMS properties. You'll have to read each message and search the payload to find and extract the text you are looking for. Maybe xml/xpath is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) you can make decisions based on message content, and act as a client to pretty much anything you can think of, including JMS brokers, REST/SOAP web service providers and send/receive plain HTTP requests.

In a Camel route in your application, you can filter on messages that match a particular XPath expression (called CBR, *content-based routing*), in your case:

```
from("<source-endpoint>")
  .choice()
    .when(xpath("/response/responseHeader/recordType == ..."))
      .to("<destination-endpoint>")
    .otherwise()
      .log("skipping record ${exchangeId}");
```

Since Camel is easy to integrate with any Java environment (no container requirements imposed), you should have no problem implementing this in your application.